# How to select WooCommerce products by post_meta and order them

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to select products with the following post_meta keys: `_product_new`, `_product_almost_new` and `_product_old`.

My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_vtp_shop_order' );

function custom_vtp_shop_order($q){
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if (! is_admin() && (is_shop() || is_archive) ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'Sold', 'Service' ),  
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

        $q->set('meta_query', array(array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                'product_new' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_new',
                    'value' => '1',
                ),
                'product_almost_new' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_almost_new',
                    'value' => '1',
                ), 
                'product_old' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_old',
                    'value' => '1',
                )
            )));

        /*THIS HAS NO EFFECT*/
        $q->set('orderby', array(array( 
                'product_new' => 'DESC',
                'product_old' => 'DESC',
                'product_almost_new' => 'DESC',
            )        
        ));

    }

}
```

I want the products to then be displayed in the following order:

1. product_new
2. product_old
3. product_almost_new

I am using $q->set('orderby', array(......) but this is having no effect. My products are ALWAYS being ordered `product_old`, `product_almost_new`, `product_new`.

Any ideas why my 'orderby' is not working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did all right except one thing. You have used array in array in orderby which is not correct.
Here is how it should look like:

```
$q->set('orderby', array(
                'product_new' => 'DESC',
                'product_almost_new' => 'DESC',
                'product_old' => 'DESC',
            )        
        );
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, but 'orderby' is still having no effect

Comment: in the given code yoi have written: 'product_new' => 'DESC',
                'product_old' => 'DESC',
                'product_almost_new' => 'DESC',  But you should write them in right order: 'product_new' => 'DESC', 'product_almost_new' => 'DESC', 
                'product_old' => 'DESC',

Comment: _new, _old, _almost_new is the order I want but the output is always _old, _almost_new, _new. Is it possible to sort by multiple meta_values for different keys?

Comment: now i got what you mean. no, your approach is not for these kind of cases. Using multiple orderby-s is for the cases where the same post ID has all given meta keys (f.e. Country, City, District) and needs to be ordered by them. But in your case each product has only one of these given meta fields. So you need to change your approach. Instead of using 3 different meta keys use just one : _product_state which has possible values  "old, new, almost_new", then easily sort your posts by new meta_key.  With small php script you can update existing posts and insert new meta to all off them.